# Issue with BufferedReader.readLine using sbt run or sbt console

Tags: scala, io, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

My question is quick I'm working on a small console for reading input in and then calling the appropriate code. I'm using sbt and I've encountered an issue where when I try to read input after running my program with sbt run, inside sbt console, or even in the plain old scala interpreter.

The prompt appears to just hang, but if I hit return it does actually read the input in. Though the  shell's buffer remains empty. Here is the general code I've been trying that has been giving me the issue.

```
import java.io._

val s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) 

val line = s.readLine

println(line)
```

Does anyone know why this is, and if so is there a way to fix this? I would love to be able to see what I type when I run my program from sbt. Without seeing my typing in the shell it makes the testing and development of my project much less enjoyable.

Answer (score -1):

This is really a Java API question, although in Scala.  BufferedReader.readLine() will consume all the characters you type from System.in until it has a whole line, at which time it will return the line as you said.

Console input was difficult in Java with the original java.io classes. Prior to Java6, I've seen a couple of messy solutions to this, but fortunately a new class was introduced with that release to make it much easier: [java.io.Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html). I think it then becomes as simple as

```
val line = System.console.readLine

println(line)
```

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I try running your code from within sbt. Specifically, the `console` is null.